# Directivity index measurement - steps to follow

Tags: acoustics, setup, measurements

I am interested in measuring the directivity index of a loudspeaker. I have been looking on the Internet information about the setup, but unfortunately the information I have found so far has to do with the mathematical expressions. Luckily I have access to the Uni's anechoic chamber to made it there. Nevertheless, I am not sure about what the procedure is. What I can suppose is that I have to use the turn table, but cannot say anything beyond that.
Thanks in advance and happy 2018 :)

Comment: I'm afraid I've forgotten the math (but you've found it already) but you need to measure its SPL @ 1m, usually using a 1kHz sine wave as source signal, at all different angles. This should give you the measurements to use the math on. If I got it from the quick search I did, you need to work out the directivity *factor* (Q) first and then work out the index. The factor is 1 if the speaker is omni (most unlikely), 2 if it's 180 degrees and 4 if it's 90 degrees and obviously, anything in between.